# PERL::DBI Getting user databases in a list

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am trying to make a little script to extract databases/tables/columns from my database, but in the first step I couldn't move on, I am getting databases in strange list, please look:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

$host = "localhost";
$user = "wnyclick_siteusr";
$pw = "Hank0402\$";

$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";
$connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);
$databases = $connect->selectcol_arrayref('show databases');

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $databases;
```

executing this code giving me the following:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'information_schema',
          'wnyclick_sitedatawp'
        ];
```

How can I put this execution result in a list?

```
print @VAR1[0];
print @databases[0];
```

Comment: The double-quotes (`"`) for your `$pw` variable will interpolate your `\$` to `$`, so the backslash will be gone from the string. If you don't want that to happen, or just want a `$`, use single-quotes (`'`) instead. Also, always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just modified your code. Try the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

my $user = "wnyclick_siteusr";
my $pw   = "Hank0402\$";

#Connecting Database
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:mysql:database=mysql;host=localhost;port=3306', '$user', '$pw' )
    or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sql = "show databases";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    #print $row[1];
    print "@row\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen, it worked after some modification, I had to remove '' beside user and pass and I had to remove mysql beside database because the server told me that user don't have rights to access database named mysql.